# mysql join query

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using the 2 following MySQL tables:

**Sample tbl_customers Dataset**

```
+----+--------+---------------+----------+------------+--------+------------+
| id | name   | email         | phone    | product_id | year   | dnt        |          
+----+--------+---------------+----------+------------+--------+------------+
| 2  | tester | test@test.com | 12345678 | 75         | 2010   | 2011/01/01 |
+----+--------+---------------+----------+------------+---------------------+
```

**Sample tbl_products Dataset**

```
+----+----------------+---------------+--------------+
| id | name           | cost          | dnt          |          
+----+----------------+------------------------------+
| 75  | product1      | 500           | 2011/01/01   |
+----+----------------+---------------+--------------+
```

want to join both tables.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
SELECT c.id,c.email,c.phone,CONCAT(c.year,c.id) AS customer_ID,p.name
FROM table_customer c
JOIN table_product p
ON p.id=c.product_id
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *, 
CONCAT(tbl_customers.year, tbl_customers.id) as customer_id,
product_name as tbl_products.name,
customer_id as tbl_customers.id,
FROM tbl_customers 
JOIN tbl_products ON (tbl_customers.product_id = tbl_products.id)
```

Comment: You're missing the "customer_id(CONCAT(YEAR AND ID))" part

Comment: I also missed the redundant naming of `id` and `name`

Comment: thanks for helping it out, i get confuse about mysql join queries, thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a nice visual explanation of JOIN's with practical examples: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html

Answer (score 0):

```
select c.id, c.email, c.phone, CONCAT(c.year,' ',c.id), p.name
from tbl_customers c inner join tbl_products p
on c.product_id = p.id
```

Comment: can you even add from table name in your query.

Comment: @seoppc - Have added. But what are you planning to do? isn't this already enough?